# Which automation tool is good for Regression testing

Tags: automation, regression

I am a java developer and new to this automation tools. I have a list of tools in which I wanted to know which is better for a web application which built using spring mvc.

These are the tools I have.

1) CasperJS
2) Cucumber
3) JMockit
4) Robot Framework

Can any one explain their experience about this tools.

Comment: This might be a better question for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any framework should be ok if you have enough experience with automation to use them efficiently.

Since your project is java based i would use a java based framework, for example jbehave (Cucumber + java) and if you don't want to use gherkin you could just use selenium webdriver.

Why i would use a java framework? maybe the dev's from your team could help later with some advanced features for setup using databases, api's etc.